# How can passing the Entity's logical name on a ConditionExpression for the ObjectTypeCode work?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, query-expressions

I have this piece of code:

```
new QueryExpression
{
    EntityName = "systemform",
    ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("name"),
    Criteria =
    {
        Conditions =
        {
            new ConditionExpression("objecttypecode", ConditionOperator.Equal, "account")
        }
    }
}
```

I can replace `"account"` with the Entity's actual `ObjectTypeCode` and both approaches work. Does CRM infer the `ObjectTypeCode` via the logical name to make this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.metadata.entitymetadata.objecttypecode.aspx)

> Always use the entity schema name (SchemaName) to refer to a custom
>   entity in code and queries. Do not use the object type code (also
>   referred to as entity type) code because tis integer value varies for
>   custom entities in different organizations.

Going by the recommendation guidelines, yes, CRM does seem to resolve the `objecttypecode` from the logical name and it almost suggests that the other way around (resolving obecttypecode from an integer value) might not always work for custom entities across different organizations.